# How are we switching from multiplication to decimals for this example of mathematical induction?

Tags: induction

Perhaps I am not seeing something but the example in my textbook on a chapter for mathematical induction asks to prove, for all $n\geq1$,

$$P(n):\frac{1}{1.2}+\frac{1}{2.3}+\frac{1}{3.4}+...+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{n}{n+1}$$
It **explicitly** states,
$$P(1):\frac{1}{1.2}=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{1+1}$$
Is true so we can proceed with further induction... but 1 over 1.2 is **not** the same as 0.5. And bluntly put, this is simply where I am stuck. I have never come across a question of this sort where the relation between numbers exists *within itself*, so to say. And I'm not quite sure whether there is a way to describe 'values' within the numbers such as the example above where the number in the tenths place is 1 more than that in the ones place.
So in short,

> How do I interpret the $n(n+1)$ in the above equation?

For further clarity, I am currently interpreting it as multiplication as you would normally. I also do not know the name given to such a relation.

Comment: The dots are meant to be read as multiplication. This is fairly common in some older textbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not decimals. They are multiplication dots that should be centered on their lines.

By coincidence, in their one explicit example
$$
"1.2" = 1 \cdot 2 = 2 = 1 + 1.
$$